# Customizing markdown-enhanced-preview

Tags: markdown, preview

Once again a newbe question about MD Preview.

I use a lot MD and Mermaid languages with Atom (and BEdit) but I'm definitly not a programer.

In Atom, I've installed markdown-enhanced-preview a long time ago. I tweaked it a little bit with colors and things like that, and I everything was beautiful.

Today, I need to make a small changing for the rendering. I want to increase a little bit the size of h3 titles. And after hours of researching, I never found again the files when I made the changes... It's not in `styles.less` or in `atom-dark.less`. There is somewhere a file  wish overrules the rest.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks a lot.
GG

Answer (score 0):

I found... just you to know what you already know :

There is simply an other style.less file : /Users/my_name/.mume/style.less (on Mac).

Tschüss
GG